# Python os and gob: Different results when executing a script on a single file vs. multiple files

Tags: python

I am writing a python shell script that has the option to execute a function (that writes a set of means from a 2D numpy array to a data file) on either a single .wav file or all .wav files in a specified directory.

For example,

```
> myscript.py --file=audio.wav --data="data.tab"
```

should write a floating point value to data.tab.

```
> myscript.py --path="path/with/audio_files" --data="data.tab"
```

should write a set of floating point values to data.tab.

I have a folder with a bunch of WAV files. When I execute the path on a single file (with the --file option), the result is different than the result when file gets processed with the --path option.

I have implemented the path file 3 ways:

1) Using os.listdir()

```
for audioFile in os.listdir(options.path):
    if audioFile.endswith('.wav'):
        foo(audioFile)
```

2) Using os.walk()

```
for r, d, f in os.walk(options.path):
for audioFile in f:
    if audioFile.endswith('.wav'):
            foo(audioFile)
```

3) Using glob.glob()

```
for audioFile in glob.glob("*.wav"):
    foo(audioFile)
```

Methods 1 and 2 return the same result. Method 3 returns a different result. All 3 methods return a different result than processing a single file.

What is going differently when I use the os or gob modules?

EDIT:
Here is where I process all .wav files in a directory:

```
for r, d, f in os.walk(options.path): 
    for audioFile in f:
        if audioFile.endswith('.wav'):  
            # Add MFCC 1-12 to data.
            mfcc12(audioFile, sampleRate, data)
```

This is in mfcc12():

```
# mfccs is a 2D numpy array. 
# Each column corresponds to one feature of the audiofile
for i in range(mfccs[0].size):
    mfccMean = mfccs[:, i].mean()
    mfccStdDev = mfccs[:, i].std()  
    data.write(str(mfccMean) + '\t' + str(mfccStdDev) + '\t')
```

I am using [YAAFE](http://yaafe.sourceforge.net/) to extract the features from the audio files.

Comment: @CppLearner They write a row of extracted feature values (means from a numpy array) from audio files into a tab-delimited file (.tab). For some reason, the written feature values for a given audio file differ depending on whether I process the file on its own or if the file is processed along with other files in the path.

Comment: Give us an example we can actually test where they return different things.

Comment: `for audioFile in glob.glob("*.wav"): print files` looks strange: shouldn't that be `print audioFile`?

Comment: I am fairly sure that you cannot rely on the order in which the files are returned, so maybe the data is just mingled up in your output file?

Comment: @SebastianBlask I ruled this out by adding a print statement that prints out the order in which the data was written. The data for a file, e.g. audio01.wav, differs depending on whether it was extracted on its own or with other files.

Answer (score 1):

The `glob` functions do the Unix-style thing of omitting files whose name starts with `.`:

```
>>> os.listdir('.')
['conn.c', 'Makefile', 'conn.o', '.depend', 'conn.c.orig', 'conn']
>>> glob.glob('*')
['conn.c', 'Makefile', 'conn.o', 'conn.c.orig', 'conn']
```

(note, `fnmatch.fnmatch` does *not* do this; the code to skip dot-files is in `glob.glob1`).
Presumably you have some dot-files.

Comment: There are no dot-files in my directory that are .wav files.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem. The problem was not with my mfcc extraction settings, not the Python code.